# Is there a way to package a desktop application from my sencha project

Tags: sencha-touch-2, tidesdk, packager

I have a sencha project which works perfect on (Safari & Chrome) from index.html. I want to create a dmg file (executable) so that i can deploy on other pc. I tried it with TideSDK. But some functionality like data retrieval from store, scrolling, refreshing screens does not work  properly. Sencha Packager(trial version) was working perfect. But now expired!!!
Any suggestion for desktop packaging a sencha project. 
Any modification i need to do before creating a TideSDK output?
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Adobe AIR? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html
I know it for years, it's cross-platform and works well with html/js/css solutions.

Comment: I tried adobe air. my simple hello.html got packed and opened perfectly. But when i give the Sencha project's index.html, i get this error"myTest.xmlError: Adobe AIR runtime security violation for JavaScript code in the application security sandbox (Function constructor)" and its open a blank screen.

Comment: Adam, any thing specific to take care.

Comment: I think sencha is posing some security issue. I get the same error on a native sencha startup project(empty) too!

Comment: Did you go through this check list: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f0e.html ? 
I also don't use compressed JS files and try to load all JS files at once before the scripts start running. Sencha may load some JS (JSON config too) files on fly which may throw "Function constructor" error.

Comment: I gone through the checklist and did few modifications. But sencha do block them!!..so gave up and went back with Tide sdk. Thanks for support..

Comment: Tide sdk has older webkit tool. I changed webkit in my sencha index.html. And now dmg works fine in Mac machines too.